# Why does this function have pole of order n=2, not 3?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\frac{1-cos(z)}{z^4}$, find the order of pole for this function at $z=0$

Initially I thought if you plug in $z=0$ you get $\frac{0}{0^4}$ so one removable singularity, thus pole is of order n=3.

However, if you taylor expand the cosine, you see that the pole order is n=2.

My question is, why is the first method wrong, and when does it/does it not work? (Because some problems the first method works fine)

Comment: Why didn't you write $\frac{0^2}{0^4}$??

Comment: because if you plug in $z=0$ to $1-cos(z)$ you get $1-1=0^1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the pole of $f$ at $z=0$ is the least $k$ such that
$$z^k f(z)$$
has a removable discontinuity at $z=0$. So the pole of this function is of order $2$ if
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z^2\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}$$
exists and is finite but
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}$$
is infinite.

Since
$$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\frac{z^6}{6!}+\cdots,$$
then
$$z^2\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}=\frac12-\frac{z^2}{4!}+\cdots,$$
so
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z^2\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}=\frac12.$$
But is easy to see, through the same reasoning, that
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}=\infty.$$

---

Of course that
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z^3\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}$$
is also finite ($0$ indeed, and the same is true for higher exponents), but since $2$ is the least exponent such that the limit
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z^k\cdot \frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^4}$$
is finite, the order of the pole is $2$.

Comment: So I realized that if you taylor expand, you get the right answer. My question was, is my original method just plain wrong? or applicable only to certain cases?

Comment: If you plug in $z=0$ you only get and indetermination and you can't say anything, since you don't know how quick each part goes to zero. In fact, the $0$ you wrote in the numerator, corresponding to $1-\cos z$, omits the fact that this expression goes to zero as fast as $z^2$; that's why you conclude that the order is $3$ and not $2$. You have to effectively calculate the limits, since an expression that goes to zero can do this at any rate.

Comment: How fast a function goes to 0 ($z^2$ or$z$ etc.)$ is something I haven't learned. So I guess it is just best to stick with the safe method of just expanding a taylor series when I see one

Comment: Actually, it is the Taylor series that tells you "how fast" some expression goes to zero. But yes, at least until you feel very comfortable with these concepts, it's better to stick to the definitions and the basic properties to decide the order of the poles.

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem with your first approach is that $1-\cos z$ has a double zero at 0 (since $\cos$ has slope 0 at 0). In general, if $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at 0 and $g$ a zero or order $j$ at 0 then $f/g$ has a zero of order $k-j$ (where a zero of order $-n$ is a pole of order $n$).

Answer (score 0):

$1 - \cos z= {1 \over 2} z^2 + \cdots $ .

So, ${1 - \cos z \over z^4} = {1 \over 2} {1 \over z^2} + \cdots $

Answer (score 0):

Because $1-\cos z=0$ when $z=0$  and note that $$\cos z=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots$$ so your function can be written as $$\frac{(\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots)}{z^4}=\frac{\phi(z)}{z^2}$$ where $\phi(z)=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{z^2}{4!} \cdots $ with $\phi(0) \neq0$